# How do I get down the elevator shaft?

Tags: half-life

I have reached the place in the game called 'Unforeseen Consequences'. There I came across a place where I get an elevator, but it crashes down. So how will I get down then?

I have tried taking the ladder down, but I land on the elevator debris. There's nowhere to go.  I have checked a walkthrough too, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Please use a walkthrough.

Comment: There has to be a better way for you to get through Half Life without asking us for help every time you get stuck...

Comment: I'm sorry but...

Comment: You're sorry but you'll keep doing it anyway. Please stop.

Comment: I knew this community is for help.. !!

Comment: Since you seem to keep getting stuck using text walkthroughs, perhaps a [video walkthrough](https://youtu.be/JoV9o6b91Sc) would be more helpful? That's what I always use if I can't find a clear answer from a text-based guide.

Comment: @rahuldarox Yes, we are, but we are not a one stop shop to hold your hand through a video game.

Comment: This community is certainly for helping, indeed.  However, you won't get a very good reception if it looks like you're not really trying to solve it yourself.  We respond much better when it looks like there's effort on your part.  The more you put in, the more you get out.

Comment: Having a glance at your profile it's taking you DAYS to scale two corridors on the first level ... This is probably not the game for you, given people have speed-run it in 20 minutes. You've been stuck three times on the first level on the first stage so far, you can't imagine how much more complex it gets later on. Stop now and go play something more tutorially

Answer (score 4):

There's a ladder to the left of the door. You just need to go all the way up to the top floor and jump to the platform.

1:45